# Calculating Time Complexity for nested loops

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

Got this question on a test that I've been stuck on for a few days regarding Big O time complexity analysis:

Below is the C code:

```
   if ( A > B ) {
       for ( i=0; i<n^2/100; i++ ){     //1
           for ( j=n^2; j>i; j-- ){     //2
               A += B;}}
   }
   else {
       for ( i=0; i<2n; i++ ){         //3   
           for ( j=3n; j>i; j-- ){     //4
               A += B;}}
   }
```

My first instinct was that this algorithm would have a big O of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* with the nested for loops and such but it wasn't a multiple choice answer. Tried to count each loop iteration manually but having trouble accounting for the changing i in each inside loop (2 and 4). Also having trouble trying to write it as a summation.

Comment: The first one isn't nested over `n` but over `n` squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first case where `A > B`. The inner loop executes a number of iterations equal to `n^2 - i` for each value of `i` iterated over by the outer loop. Consider `n = 2` and `i = 1`. `n^2 = 4` and the inner loop iterates over `j = 4, j = 3, j = 2`, three iterations, consistent with our finding.

The total number of iterations of the inner loop is therefore the sum of all `n^2 - i` where `i` varies from `0` to `floor(n^2/100) - 1`. Let us define `k := floor(n^2/100) - 1`. Then this sum is equal to `kn^2 - k(k+1)/2`. Substituting the expression for which `k` stands we recover `[floor(n^2/100) - 1]n^2 - [floor(n^2/100) - 1][floor(n^2/100)]/2`. This is no greater than `(n^2/100 - 1)n^2 - (n^2/100 - 1)(n^2/100)/2`. We may multiply through to get `n^4/100 - n^2 - n^4/20000 + n^2/200 = n^4(1/100 - 1/20000) - n^2(1 - 1/200)`. From this we can see that the time complexity of the first case is `O(n^4)`. Indeed, it is also `Omega(n^4)` and `Theta(n^4)`.

In the case where `A <= B`, the analysis is similar. It is easy to show that the time complexity of the second case is `O(n^2)`, `Omega(n^2)` and thus `Theta(n^2)`.

Therefore, we may confidently say that:

- The worst-case time complexity is `O(n^4)`;
- The best-case time complexity is `Omega(n^2)`;
- Each of these bounds may actually be given as `Theta` bounds instead.

Comment: It is not right to separate the cases to give big O. For example  quicksort is O(n^2) not O(n) which is the medium time complexity. Big O must covers all cases!

Comment: @coder *quicksort is O(n^2)* It is more correct to say that the worst-case time complexity of quicksort is `O(n^2)`. Quicksort itself is an algorithm, not a function that is bounded by any numerical sequence.

Comment: The above algorithm-program can't have big O depending on cases ,you have to choose a function that denotes the worst case of the above algorithm. It was asked time-complexity of the above algorithm-program and not in special cases...it is not asked to find an upper bound function  (a function that is bounded by any numerical sequence) nor in cases ,it is clear big O of algorithm (just like big O of quicksort and evry other allgorithm)

Comment: @coder The worst case is when `A > B`. In that case, the time complexity is `O(n^4)`. The best case is when `A <= B`. In that case, the time complexity is `Omega(n^2)`. I fail to see what is problematic about this analysis. If you are only interested in an upper bound on the worst case, as is frequently the case in the analysis of algorithms, you might say that "the algorithm is O(n^4)". But that is an informal abbreviation of what is really intended.